# Usar variable "Boolean" en un procedimiento almacenado en MySQL

Tags: stored-procedure, booleano

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE pa_categoriapermiso 
(
    IN Funcion INT,
    IN Id_CategoriaPermisos INT,
    IN Nombre_CatPer VARCHAR(50),
    IN Siglas_CatPermisos VARCHAR(10),
    IN Descripción VARCHAR(100),
    OUT Sw BOOL
)
BEGIN
    If (Funcion = 1) --Registrar Categoria de Permiso
            INSERT INTO `tbl_categoria_permisos`
            (`Id_CategoriaPermisos`, `Nombre_CatPer`, `Siglas_CatPermisos`, `Descripción`, `Activo`, `Fecha_Hora`)
        VALUES
            (NULL, Nombre_CatPer, Siglas_CatPermisos, Descripción, UNHEX('1'), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
        ElseIf (Funcion = 2) --Modificar Categoria de Permiso
                UPDATE 
                    `tbl_categoria_permisos`
                        SET 
                        `Nombre_CatPer`=Nombre_CatPer,
                        `Siglas_CatPermisos`=Siglas_CatPermisos,
                        `Descripción`=Descripción,
                        `Fecha_Hora`=[value-6] 
                WHERE 
                    Id_CategoriaPermisos = Id_CategoriaPermisos
                Sw = True
        ElseIf (Funcion = 3) --Eliminar Categoria de Permiso
                UPDATE 
                    `tbl_categoria_permisos`
                        SET 
                        `Activo`=UNHEX('0'),
                WHERE 
                    `Id_CategoriaPermisos` = Id_CategoriaPermisos
                DECLARE Activo INT

        SELECT Activo=`Activo` FROM  `tbl_categoria_permisos` WHERE `Id_CategoriaPermisos` = Id_CategoriaPermisos

                If Activo==0
                    Sw = True
                else
                    Sw = False
                End If;
        ElseIf (Funcion >= 4) --ERROR
            Sw = False
        END IF;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Quiero que me ayuden a hacer ese procedimiento almacenado, que cuando se realice el ABM (Agregar, Baja y Modificar) correctamente que me devuelva un verdadero o falso según lo que ocasiona el resultado...

Comment: Modifica la pregunta para añadirle la estructura de la base de datos en SQL (phpMyAdmin, Exportar), así podremos depurar el procedimiento almacenado. En incluye cambién lo que quieres obtener, no como comentario: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: ¿Has abandonado esta pregunta? Hemos quedado a la espera de que la modifiques, aportando más datos, para poder ayudarte :) Por favor, incluye como etiqueta el sistema gestor que utilizas: sql-server, mysql, ...